# Imask и Just-validate не работают совместно

Tags: javascript, form, валидация, inputmask, just-validate

Подскажите пожалуйста, почему может не работать валидация с помощью плагина just-validate для инпута, на который установлена маска с помощью плагина Imask?

```js
import IMask from "imask";

document.querySelectorAll('.phone-mask').forEach((e) => {
    const phoneMask = IMask(e, { mask: '+{7} (000) 000-00-00' })
})


import JustValidate from "just-validate";

const validation = new JustValidate('.form-hero');

validation
    .addField('.phone-mask', [
        {
            rule: 'required',
            value: true,
            errorMessage: 'Введите номер телефона',
        },
        {
            rule: 'function',
            validator: function () {
                const phone = phoneMask.IMask.unmaskedValue();
                return phone.length === 10;
            },
            errorMessage: 'Введите корректный номер телефона'
        }
    ])
```